# Print only the "name" atribute in the listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

Im working on a android app where the first screen is a listview that is supposed just to show the name of the series inserted into the app, at the moment it´s printing all the information i have about the serie,i want to know:

- How can i print just the name of the serie on the first screen.
- Print all the information of the serie when i click in one serie on the first screen.

**MainActivity:**

```
    package com.example.bugdroid.trabalhoapp1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.bugdroid.trabalhoapp1.modelo.Series;
import com.example.bugdroid.trabalhoapp1.modelo.Serie;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_series);

        Series Series = new Series();

        Serie exemplo = new Serie ("Thrones", "açao", 50, 10, 1900 );
        Series.getLista().add(exemplo);

        exemplo = new Serie("CSI", "Policial", 30, 20, 4);
        Series.getLista().add(exemplo);

        exemplo = new Serie("Flash", "aventura", 30, 20, 4);
        Series.getLista().add(exemplo);

        exemplo = new Serie("Vikings", "Historia", 3, 2, 4);
        Series.getLista().add(exemplo);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Series.getLista());

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**Serie.java**

```
    package com.example.bugdroid.trabalhoapp1.modelo;

/**
 * Created by BugDroid on 06/05/2016.
 */
public class Serie {

    private String nome;
    private String descricao;
    private int nEpisodios;
    private int nTemporadas;
    private int dataEstreia;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public int getnEpisodios() {
        return nEpisodios;
    }

    public void setnEpisodios(int nEpisodios) {
        this.nEpisodios = nEpisodios;
    }

    public int getnTemporadas() {
        return nTemporadas;
    }

    public void setnTemporadas(int nTemporadas) {
        this.nTemporadas = nTemporadas;
    }

    public int getDataEstreia() {
        return dataEstreia;
    }

    public void setDataEstreia(int dataEstreia) {
        this.dataEstreia = dataEstreia;
    }

    public Serie () {
        this.nome = "";
        this.descricao = "";
        this.nEpisodios = 0;
        this.nTemporadas = 0;
        this.dataEstreia = 0;
    }

    public Serie(String nome, String c, int p, int h, int g){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = c;
        this.nEpisodios = p;
        this.nTemporadas = h;
        this.dataEstreia = g;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String res = "A serie" + this.nome + " tem a seguinte descricao " + this.descricao + "com" + this.nEpisodios + "episodios e " + this.nTemporadas + "estreou em" + this.dataEstreia +")";
        return res;
    }
}
```

**Series.java**

```
    package com.example.bugdroid.trabalhoapp1.modelo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by BugDroid on 07/05/2016.
 */
public class Series {

    private ArrayList<Serie> lista;

    public ArrayList<Serie> getLista(){
        return this.lista;
    }

    public void setLista(ArrayList<Serie> l){
        this.lista = l;
    }

    public Series(){
        this.lista = new ArrayList<Serie>();
    }

    public Series(ArrayList<Serie> l){
        this.lista = new ArrayList<Serie>(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a class for `Series` since it is only an `Arraylist<Serie>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change the toString methode as cricket_007 tolds you it's the easy way.
to print all the infos you have `Serie` to implement the `Serializable`

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long itemID) {

       Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Detail.class);
       in.putExtra("data", Series.getLista().get(itemID));
       startActivity(in);
    }
});
```

and at the Detail class you have to

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
```

Comment: Hello and thanks ! I am newbie on this, should i create one class " Serializable" and then make Serie implement it ?

Comment: your Serie class must impliments the Serializable interface just like that

Comment: What is the Detail class and where should i put the code you mentioned ? This should sound really noobish, sry :) Thanks.

Comment: you have to put the getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data"); at the activity where you want to parse all the informations. it will return a Serie Object

Comment: And the lv.setOnItem.CliclListener thing ? On the new activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `toString` method.

```
public String toString() {
    return this.nome;
}
```

Alternatively, you can define a custom ArrayAdapter and layout for your data.

To print all the information, on click, you need an `OnItemClickListener` on your ListView.